# Add-AppxProvisionedPackage fails on PowerShell (x86)

Tags: powershell, uwp

I'm trying to build an installer to sideload a Windows 10 application.  At one point the installer calls PowerShell (x86) to run the following command:

```
Add-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online -PackagePath $pkgPth -DependencyPackagePath $dp1Pth,$dp2Pth,$dp3Pth -SkipLicense
```

That's where I get this error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0xC1570108): The package
>   does not meet the requirement for provisioning to the target image.

When I try the command with the 64 bit version of PowerShell, the installation runs just fine.

The package that I built is a x86 package.  The the dependency paths all point to the x86 dependencies.  Looking through [Microsoft's documentation for the Add-AppxProvisionedPackage cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/add-appxprovisionedpackage?view=win10-ps), I cannot see anything else that might suggest an issue with the x86 version.

I have sideloading enabled, and I've installed the developer certificate (and the error message doesn't suggest those would be problems anyway).  I'm also running PowerShell as an administrator.

Is there something I'm missing when building the package (as the error message would lead me to believe)?  Or is there something missing from my call to Add-AppxProvisionedPackage?

UPDATE:
I tried writing a batch file to call DISM instead of using PowerShell.  It works as long as I manually call the batch file, but when the installer calls the batch file I get the same 0xC1570108 error that I got when using PowerShell (x86).

I'm not sure it's relevant, but I'm using NSIS for my installer, and I call the batch file like this:

```
nsExec::ExecToLog '$INSTDIR\path\mybat.bat $SOME_ARGS'
```

Comment: so ... how are you starting 32bit PoSh?

Comment: From my installer I use psexec.nsh (https://nsis.sourceforge.io/PowerShell_support), but I get the same thing when I just open PowerShell and run the script

Comment: if you "just open powershell" ... you are NOT running 32bit powershell unless your OS is 32bit. at this point i am lost for ideas, tho, so i will go back to lurking ... i wish you the best of good luck! [*grin*]

Comment: I should have said "just opened PowerShell (x86)". Obviously, when I "just open PowerShell", the script works.  Anyway, thanks for trying.

Comment: you are welcome .... glad to kinda-sorta help. [*grin*]